# rollover/out buttons( text) dont work with tween

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

here i have some xml buttons and when i want to do tween on current button that tweend dont work on text dont know why and when i want to remove event listener from current button on rollover its dont work to

here is my code

```
    xmlBtn.buttonMode = true;
    xmlBtn.mouseChildren = false;
    xmlBtn.useHandCursor = true;
    xmlBtn.addEventListener("rollOver",rollOverHandler);
    xmlBtn.addEventListener("rollOut",rollOutHandler);

    function rollOverHandler(event:MouseEvent) {
             var rollOverBtn:xmlLinkButton = event.target as xmlLinkButton;
        //fadeIn = new Tween ( rollOverBtn , "alpha" , None.easeOut , 1 , 0.5  , 25 , false );
        rollOverBtn.alpha = 0.8;

// for now this line is only option for me but i want that text have tween
        rollOverBtn.butonText.visible = false;


        if (rollOverBtn == event.target ){
            trace( rollOverBtn.source );
        }
    }

    function rollOutHandler(event:MouseEvent) {
        var rollOutBtn:xmlLinkButton = event.target as xmlLinkButton;
        //fadeIn = new Tween ( rollOutBtn , "alpha" , None.easeIn , 0.6 , 1 , 25 , false );
        rollOutBtn.alpha = 1;
        rollOutBtn.butonText.visible = true;
    }
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly because both Tweens (in `rollOutHandler` and in `rollOverHandler`) have the same values?

Have you embedded the font(s)?

Comment: no its not im allredy try , but acidenti i paste here the same tween ill change that now .

Comment: How about the fonts? In order to tween the opacity fonts need to be embedded.

Comment: lol :) great newer embedded fonts before i finish project on works fine TNX a lot